# How to solve Check Component Dependency Error in magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento-2.0

Here I show my problem in image file

Can any one help me how to solve this problem?

[image: How to solve Check Component Dependency Error in magento 2.1.1]

Show This Error:

> Check Component Dependency
>   We found conflicting component dependencies. Hide detail
>
> Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>   - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.1].
>   - magevision/module-free-shipping-admin 2.1.0 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.2].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.3].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.4].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.5].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.6].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.7].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.8].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.9].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.10].
>   - Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.1, 100.0.11].
>   - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.1 requires magento/framework 100.1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.1].
>   - Installation request for magevision/module-free-shipping-admin 2.1.0 -> satisfiable by magevision/module-free-shipping-admin[2.1.0].
>
> For additional assistance, see component dependency help .

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue.

You need to update php memory limits in `.htaccess` and `.user.ini` files in Magento root directory from 765MB to 2G as they override system php limits.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the extension you're installing expects Magento 2.0.x but you're using 2.1.x.

This leads me to believe that either the extension authors either:

Aren't ready to support Magento 2.1

or

They have erroneously constrained their packages requirements by accident, not [understanding Composer's versioning scheme](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md).

Referencing the extension you're installing on Github we can see it [specifies some requirements](https://github.com/magevision/magento2-free-shipping-admin/blob/master/composer.json):

```
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-store": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-shipping": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-backend": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-quote": "100.0.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"   
}
```

Let's take a look at one of the modules required by the extension: `magento/module-config` with a version constraint of `100.0.*`.

I can see that [Magento 2.0.10](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/60fcebc2b5209fd2bde35be3b0bc796a0dd56f37/composer.json#L105) would supply a compatible version `100.0.5`.

Whereas you have [Magento 2.1.1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2765acf04833b2a3add26b68d45cf833f530f53b/composer.json#L103) installed, which requires version `100.1.1`.

`100.1.1` does not satisfy the `100.0.*` requirement.

**There are roughly two solutions to your problem**

1. Use Magento 2.0 (not ideal but could unblock you to play around with the extension)
2. Get in touch with the extension developer and see if they intend to support Magento 2.1 (either by updating their code to be compatible or fixing their package to allow installation under 2.1)

Answer (score 0):

You may see **require-dev** tag in **composer.json** file.

Run composer install or update with `--no-dev` flag. This will not install developer dependency packages.

```
composer install --no-dev
```

OR

```
composer update --no-dev
```